# Django: Maintainable drop down choices

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a newbie problem(sorry for the bad english).

I am trying to make a maintainable drop down choices on the address part of my project.

Let's say that I have these models:

```
class STATES(models.Model):
    state= models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CITIES(models.Model):
    fkey = models.ForeignKey(STATES)
    CITY = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.CITY
```

And forms

```
class address(ModelForm):
    state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = STATES.objects.all())
    CITY = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = CITIES.objects.all())
class Meta:
    model = REGIONS
    fields = ('state', 'CITY',)
```

How do i make the form display the cities that is in the state that I selected?

Any pointers, advice, links, or even a sample code would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your own, you need ajax to help you. You need to capture the dropdown change of your `state`, then using ajax to load the `city` and display it in the template. There's no shortcut in django to do that. Otherwise take the third party package like https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects, it would simplify this process.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, I was wondering if I could use ajax only to display the changes so that it would be more simple but it seems that it's not possible. Thanks, will try :)